# Dropping in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe in the form of:

```
no   ans   freq
1    Yes    23
     No     89
2    Yes    45
     No     76
3    Yes    99
```

I would like to drop ones that only have Yes or only NO as the second index (no and ans are indices). This would give:

```
no   ans   freq
1    Yes    23
     No     89
2    Yes    45
     No     76
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What error are you getting, or what don't you understand?

Comment: How to drop them. No idea how to drop multiindex rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could `groupby` "no" and transform to get the group size. If 2 keep, else drop:

```
df[df.groupby(level='no')['freq'].transform('size').eq(2)]
```

input:

```
        freq
no ans      
1  Yes    23
   No     89
2  Yes    45
   No     76
3  Yes    99
```

output:

```
        freq
no ans      
1  Yes    23
   No     89
2  Yes    45
   No     76
```